# Using Structure from another class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a slight problem during the implementation of my program.
Is there a way to use a structure declared in another class?

```
Example

Class A{
 struct personA
 {
   char name[MAX];
   char nationality[MAX];
 }

 void addPersonA(fstream, int, personA);
}

Class B{
 struct personB
 {
   char nameB[MAX];
   char nationalityB[MAX];
 }

 void addPersonB(fstream, int, personB);
}

//Class A.CPP
Class_A
{

int choice;

cin >> choice;

   if(choice == 1)
{
personA a;
addPersonA(afile, num, a);

}

else
{

personB b; // how do i include this part?

addPersonB(afile, num, b); // this part error. b is not defined.

}

}
```

The problem is personB is not declared in scope.

header file for Class_A.cpp has the following includes

```
#include "Class_A.h" 
#include "Class_B.h"
```

Comment: First of all, remember that the default visibility of classes are `private`.

Comment: Another notes: 'class' keyword must be in lowercase; if 'fstream' is std::fstream, you can't pass it as value (only as reference/pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `personA` public:

```
class A
{
public:

 struct personA
 {
   char name[MAX];
   char nationality[MAX];
 }

 void addPersonA(fstream, int, personA);
}
```

To access a child class/struct you need to use a fully qualified name:

```
if(choice == 1)
{
  A::personA a;
  addPersonA(afile, num, a);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `personB` be accessible by `class A` (using `public` or `friend`), and scope it as `B::personB`.